# No message body writer has been found for response class ArrayList [jboss 7]

Tags: java, rest, cxf, jboss7.x, resteasy

Our application with restful services are working fine on jboss 6, after upgrading to jboss 7, none of the rest services are working.

Exception we encountered is http 500 internal server error:

```
One of the restful service error is:
    INFO  - HTTP Status Code: 500
    INFO  - Web Service call execution: 1410 ms.
    INFO  - Content-Length: null
    INFO  - Content-Type: text/plain
    INFO  - Message-Body: **No message body writer has been found for response class ArrayList.**
```

application has the following dependencies.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-bundle-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
   <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

After analysis I found that the jboss has rest easy api which is conflicting with cxf libraries.

I tried lot of options available on the web to exclude resteasy, but it didnt help.

how to exclude the jboss embedded libraries rest easy and other rest components to force jboss to use the application libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found excluding the jaxrs sub system as a whole in jboss 7 helped me to force jboss to rely on my application provided cxf and javax.ws.rs-api libraries.

I have added the file jboss-deployment-structure.xml shown below to war file to exclude jaxrs sub system.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```